# An array of vectors

Tags: r, arrays, vector, stan

I have an n-dimensional array of length 2 vectors.

```
...
vector[2] w[n];
...
```

Are the following equivalent, if I would like to perform the calculation $w_1 + w_2$

```
...
for(i in 1:n){
  Mu[i] = w[i][1] + w[i][2];
}
...
```

and

```
...
for(i in 1:n){
  Mu[i] = w[i,1] + w[i,2];
}
...
```

Comment: from what i guess, if w is a matrix. e.g, w = matrix(1:9,ncol=3,nrow=3) ; w[1][1] does not work and w[1,1] works. if it is an array, then they are equivalent, e.g w = array(1:9,dim=c(3,3)) ;  w[1][1] and w[1,1] are similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent. The answer to this question can be found here: [Answer link](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/an-array-of-vectors/11624)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're the same, as [JLee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11658951/jlee) already noted.  The other way to do this is to transpose `w` and use

```
vector[N] w_tr[2];
...
vector[N] Mu = w_tr[1] + w_tr[2];
```

You need vector types in order to add them.